# With AWS LoadBalancer how to set "Service down for maintenance"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elb

How can I set a message `Service down for maintenance` or `Service Temporarily Unavailable` on my web service that runs on Amazon Web Services using LoadBalancer.

I have a few Loadbalancers and now I need to put one down.

I'm using laravel and I can set a single instance by

```
php artisan down
```

but I have many instances.

And I'm not using Route53 on this LoadBalancer.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to be able to return a maintenance page to disable the site, even though the instances are healthy?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to return a maintenance page to disable the site, even though the instances are healthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an ALB you can set up a listener that will return a fixed response. You could make this listener with a condition you want or make it the default listener.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html

[Example image in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQZHo.png)

Comment: This answer is on the right track.  Application Load Balancers can render static responses and a configuration change to the balancer would allow a rule to be inserted to intercept traffic and reply with a static response... but, even better, you can also (now) send the request to a Lambda function, which would provide a lot more flexibility than a static response: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/lambda-functions-as-targets-for-application-load-balancers/

Answer (score -1):

Neither the ALB or ELB support this. You should either return maintenance mode content on all instances or remove all but one instance from your load balance and return maintenance mode content on the remaining instance.

You could also use DNS to send traffic to an S3 Bucket that hosts your maintenance mode content.